# MKMapView NSInvalidArgumentException Invalid Region crash in ios 9 swift?

Tags: swift

I am tried to view the MKMapView inside the TableView but it had crashed for some issue but i cant find that issue please any one help me for to clear that issue?
It shows like this...

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region center:-119.27656620, +34.26884010 span:+0.04487346, -0.12825858>'

Here i give my code what i did..

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: longarray[indexPath.row] as! Double,
        longitude: latarray[indexPath.row] as! Double

    )
    print("the json array of Longitude is  \(self.longarray[indexPath.row])")
    print("the json array of Longitude is  \(self.latarray[indexPath.row])")

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.0, 2.0)
    print("the span is  \(span)")
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    cell.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location

    cell.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is pretty straight forward: in `latitude` you are passing longitude values and for `longitude` you did the same thing, so switch them around

In your code:

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: longarray[indexPath.row] as! Double, //<-- error
        longitude: latarray[indexPath.row] as! Double  //<--- error

    )
```

the latitude property cannot receive any longitude values because they are negative

**Correct code should be :**

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: latarray[indexPath.row] as! Double,
        longitude: longarray[indexPath.row] as! Double

    )
```

Comment: Please explain i cant understand.

Comment: latarray is latitude and longarray for longitude.

Comment: yeah sir you have to match them :)

Comment: how to match...@lamour

Comment: check the answer i have been provided you with the answer my friend

Comment: @Lamar is there any way to catch and handle such exception?, in case of invalid region or latitude/longitude entered by user manually?

Comment: after you create the coordinate, func `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(CLLocationCoordinate2D)` to check whether the location is valid or not @kalpeshjetani

Comment: Thank you Lumar for quick response, actually i have set invalid region by assigning 10000 miles in span calculation

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+0.00000000, +0.00000000 span:+1449.27536232, +1449.27536232>'